# Prevent unnecessary white space in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, webstorm

Is there a way to delete unnecessary white space,two space instead of one for example, when auto formatting a JavaScript file in Webstorm

**before**

```
function   test () {
  return  'test'  ;
}
```

**after**

```
function test() {
  return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it's formatted to:

```
function test() {
  return  'test';
}
```

As I can see the only problem is with the number of spaces after `return`. I've created a new issue for it, please [star/vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13337). If you find other cases where formatting doesn't work as expected, feel free to [report them directly to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes).

Comment: Yes in this case its only after return, but there was some other case too. Will update the question when I see it again.

Comment: Please report the cases you find directly to YouTrack.